# Discord OAuth identity endpoint not authorized after adding guilds scope?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord

Upon adding a guild scope to my Discord OAuth link, the authentication token in which responds does not have access to the identity (https://discord.com/api/users/@me) redirect.

**My query parameters for the authentication is current as follows:**

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
   client_id: AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
   redirect_uri: AUTH_REDIRECT,
   response_type: 'code',
   prompts: 'consent',
   scope: 'identify%20guilds',
   state: this.uuid,
})

let url = decodeURIComponent(`${AUTH_ENDPOINT}?${queryParams}`)
```

This link successfully prompts a discord authentication, asking if I would like give permissions, when I agree the link redirects me as expected.

**I use the following code in order to receive a authentication token:**
Where 'auth' is token returned from the redirect.

```
 const access_token = await request({
   method: 'POST',
   uri: TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
   form: {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: auth,
      client_id: AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: AUTH_SECRET,
      redirect_uri: AUTH_REDIRECT
   },
   json: true
})
```

**The following code is used to get the user identity. This is the request that responds invalid access!**

```
const info = await request.get(USER_ENDPOINT, {
   headers: { Authorization: access_token.token_type + ' ' + access_token.access_token},
   json: true
})
```

**Error!**

```
{"message":"401: Unauthorized","code":0
```

Prior to adding the **%20guilds** scope, this worked fine.

**Update:**
For some reason it just seems to be my discord account that's returning unauthorized, even on just the identity scope?